# Where is the "extra" folder in Android SDK Packages Installation?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I am a beginner to Android Mobile Development. Went to the web site to install Android studio http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

If you go to point 2, where it says "Get the support library for additional APIs", and it says, "Open the Extras directory and select.."

Where is the Extras directory? I could not find it under C:\Program Files\Android. Nor did I see it when I loaded up the SDK Manager.

Experts, please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scroll all the way to the bottom in Android SDK Manager there is a Extras option with tree having Android Support Repository and so on ... 
directory will be your android sdk location \extras in my case its C:\sdk\extras if you have downloaded tools from extras [image: Extras]

extras will be created if you download something from extras.

Comment: No extras folder in Android Studio's SDK Manager.