# android sdk manager does not have any extra folder to install android support repository

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

i can't find extra folder in android SDK manager .

[image]

can anyone help ? i searched and nothing found
i want to install android support repository and there is nothing

[image]

Comment: see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30897282/2919483

Comment: i saw this link before . but i think my problem is a bit different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer . just download the android support repository(a zip file) manually and after unzip copy and replace with the m2repository folder in the extra folder in sdk path.
after doing this android support repository and much more option added to sdk manager like this :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extras have been removed You can find anything you want that existed in the old SDK manager in SDK tools tab
[image]

Comment: i want to install android support repository . but in support repository there isn't android support repository like third option in your picture

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple user profiles for the machine then it works only for one user.

Android Studio has to installed for specific user. So check once installation is done with same user profile

Comment: there is only one profile using machine . i think this problem happened for me for the first time in the world !